# Rails server do not send content-encoding Gzip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When i run a project in env Product on local. I have run cmd  `assets:precompile` to compile assets.

I request on local with content-encoding gzip, it's work (example in image).

but When i deploy to server, request get assets in not responde content-encoding gzip.

I'm use ngix server on host.
I want to setting server to send assets with encode gzip.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When running in production, Rails normally let Nginx handle all assets.
This is decided by the `config.public_file_server.enabled` configuration setting.

So, what you need to do is update nginx configuration to let it know to send the files compressed, with something like this:

```
  location ~ ^/(assets|packs)/ {
    sendfile           on;
    sendfile_max_chunk 1m;
    tcp_nopush on;
    gzip_static  on;
    if_modified_since before;
    expires 1M;
    access_log off;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
  }
```

The important part is the `gzip_static` which tells nginx to look for already compressed files (which `assets:precompile` creates)
You can also enable `gzip` in the nginx config to tell it to compress everything, and `gzip_proxied` to tell it to compress responses from rails itself.

Also, have a look at all options here: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html